# Upgrade to Apache 2.2.20 on Centos

Tags: centos, apache-2.2

We're build/maintain websites on LAMP, with Centos (5.*) running Apache (2.2.17). We're thinking of upgrading Apache to 2.2.20 and I'm wondering if there's a recommended route to achieving this? These are live sites, so obvuiously we're keen to do this with the minimum of risk; up to now we've been managing Centos via yum.

Cheers,

Toby

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Apache version 2.2.17, I wonder that you install it from [CentAlt](http://centos.alt.ru/pub/httpd/) repo. You can check it by using `repoquery` program from `yum-utils` package:

```
# repoquery -i httpd

Name        : httpd
Version     : 2.2.15
Release     : 5.el6.centos
Architecture: x86_64
Size        : 3057369
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
Group       : System Environment/Daemons
URL         : http://httpd.apache.org/
Repository  : base
Summary     : Apache HTTP Server
Description :
The Apache HTTP Server is a powerful, efficient, and extensible
web server.
```

And if so, you can upgrade Apache to the latest version (2.2.20) from this repo with:

```
# yum update httpd
```

Verify the Apache version and restart httpd:

```
# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.20 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 31 2011 14:48:47

# service httpd restart
```

Take a look at error logs to confirm they are working fine.

PS: **I strongly recommend you do it on the test server first.**

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! We've been using Jason Litka's repo (http://www.jasonlitka.com/yum-repository/), but he seems to have stopped updating. I had seen that CentAlt has 2.2.20, but I don't know anything about that repo and the site's in Russian, which unfortunately I don't speak. Consequently I feel a bit paranoid about using the repo (in case I miss a warning along the lines of "Do not use this package, it is incomplete" or something). I guess I was thinking we'd have to revert to using an RPM, and wanted to know the safest way of making the switch, but maybe there's another way?

Comment: Maybe grab the source and build your own rpm packages is the safest way.

Comment: Building your own packages is always the safest way, regardless of wherever it comes from (one less link in the chain).  That aside, I have used CentAlt packages before.  Your concerns are legitimate, just wanted to note that they worked as expected.